# ASP.NET Gridview

Tags: sql, asp.net, gridview

I formed the table shown below picture 1 with GridView but there is a something which I want and I explain that picture 2 (İ didn't use GridView there).

When the data come from database to column of `Durum`, if it is `Aktif`, it shows `Aktif` Button or if it is `Pasif`, it shows `Pasif` Button.

How can do this?

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this TemplateField Code in your GridView:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Durum">
    <ItemTemplate>

        // Bind your durum column from database in Eval
        <asp:Label ID="lblDurum" Visible="false" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("durum") %>'></asp:Label> 

        <asp:Button ID="btnAktif" Visible="false" runat="server" Text="Aktif" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnPasif" Visible="false" runat="server" Text="Pasif" />

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Button Aktif = e.Row.FindControl("btnAktif") as Button;
            Button Pasif = e.Row.FindControl("btnPasif") as Button;

            string Durum = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblDurum")).Text;
            if (Durum=="Aktif")
                Aktif.Visible = true;
            else
                Pasif.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

**Note:** Don't forget to add OnRowDataBound in GrindView `<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" >`

Answer (score 0):

You can do pretty much whatever you want assuming you don't use default column binding but rather you define your own.

```
<asp:GridView ... AutoGenerateColumns="false">
   <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField>
           <ItemTemplate>

               this is where your template can do 
               pretty much anything including conditionals

               <asp:Button runat="server" 
                   ForeColor="<%# Bind("column")=="value" ? "Red" ? "Blue" %> />
```

Note that dynamic binding can be applied to **any** property. You could have two different buttons then and dynamically bind their `Visible` property so that they are visible or hidden depending on a value of one of dataset columns.

More on dynamic templates in multiple tutorials, e.g.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx